# how do i check if hits has a value or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

My goal is to send an alarm if the [hits] field is empty.

This is my result:

```
hits: {
 total: { value: 10000, relation: 'gte' },
 max_score: 1,
 hits: [
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object]
 ]
 }
}
```

and this is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const query = {
query: {
match: {
 "kubernetes.pod.name.keyword" : "fcppaddy-596b798c77-9hwbh"
      }
     }
    };
 axios.get("https://tommaso.fachin:Indigestione!@elastic.gnet.it:9200/filebeat-7.15.2/_search? 
 pretty", query)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
    console.log(res.status);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
  });
```

Comment: are you checking `hits` or `hits.hits`?

Comment: hits @DMcCallum83

Comment: I want you to send me an alarm for every hits @DMcCallum83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100%, but from your comments it seems like you want to check if hits has anything in it, and if so do something for each one:

```
if(hits.length > 0) {
  hits.forEach((hit) => {
    triggerAlarm()
  })
}
```

So obviously you can choose what to send as a param to `triggerAlarm()` but I think this is what you're asking for

Edit, based on your comment:

```
if(hits.hits.length > 0) {
  hits.forEach((hit) => {
    // for each item in hits.hits array, send mail
    ModuloMail()
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you but it's not really like that, I want you to send me an alarm for every hits. For example if I have 10 hits I want 10 alarms @DMcCallum83

Comment: console.log(res.data.hits.total.value)
      if (res.data.hits.total.value > 0)
      {
        ModuloMail();
      }
this code send me an email if hits >0....i want to send me an alarm for every hits(cycle?)